# ¿colocar varios QGridlayout en scrollarea en QT?

Tags: c++, qt

quiero poner varios gifs en un `scrollarea`, quiero hacerlo con ayuda de un `for` este es mi código:

```
QString arr[6];
arr[0]="/imagen_1.gif";
arr[1]="/imagen_2.gif";
arr[2]="/imagen_3.gif";
arr[3]="/imagen_4.gif";
arr[4]="/imagen_5.gif";
arr[5]="/imagen_6.gif";


QGridLayout *gridLay = new QGridLayout( ); //1
QMovie *movie = new QMovie(Files_vid+arr[1]);//2


 QLabel *processLabel = new QLabel(this);//3


 processLabel->setScaledContents(true);
 processLabel->setFixedSize(100,100);
 processLabel->setMovie(movie);

 gridLay->addWidget( processLabel, 0, 0 );
 gridLay->addItem( new QSpacerItem(20,30), 0,1 );

 ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout( gridLay );
 movie->start();
```

quiero pasar todo el arreglo de Qstring con un for, tengo este codigo:

```
 QString arr[6];
arr[0]="/imagen_1.gif";
arr[1]="/imagen_2.gif";
arr[2]="/imagen_3.gif";
arr[3]="/imagen_4.gif";
arr[4]="/imagen_5.gif";
arr[5]="/imagen_6.gif";
int cont=0;

for (int k=0;k<6;k++)
{

    QGridLayout *gridLay = new QGridLayout( ); //1
    QMovie *movie = new QMovie(Files_vid+arr[k]);//2


     QLabel *processLabel = new QLabel(this);//3


     processLabel->setScaledContents(true);
     processLabel->setFixedSize(100,100);
     processLabel->setMovie(movie);

     gridLay->addWidget( processLabel, 0, cont );
     cont++;
     gridLay->addItem( new QSpacerItem(20,30), 0,cont );
     cont++;
     ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout( gridLay );
     movie->start();
}
```

pero me marca este error:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "scrollAreaWidgetContents", which already has a layout

Answer (score 1):

Un widget únicamente puede contener un layout principal. Si quieres que un widget pueda contener varios layouts lo que tienes que hacer es anidar esos layouts dentro del layout principal. También se pueden crear estructuras más complejas:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|   Layout principal -> VLayout             |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
| |            HLayout                    | |
| | +----------------+ +----------------+ | |
| | |  Grid layout   | |   VLayout      | | |
| | +----------------+ +----------------+ | |
| |                                       | |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
|                                           |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
| |              Grid layout              | |
| +---------------------------------------+ |
|                                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Así pues, si quieres crear un collage de GridLayout, lo que tienes que hacer es una estructura de layouts anidados.

En el ejemplo yo he puesto el layout principal de tipo `VLayout`, pero es únicamente un ejemplo. El layout principal puede ser del tipo que quieras, la única restricción es que solo puede haber un layout principal